# summarize memory use task manager

Tags: windows, memory-usage, task-manager

There are multiple processes (several dozens) running on a Windows 7 Pro machine. They have the same Image Name (column Image Name in Windows Task Manager), but can take various amount of memory (column Private Working Set in Windows Task Manager).

What is the quickest and most relevant way of summarizing the memory usage for them altogether? I basically want to select them all and see the summary of memory usage at the current moment of time (does not have to be real time, can be a static value obtained at a certain point of time when summarizing).

Answer (score 2):

Powershell :

```
PS H:\> Get-Process  chrome | measure PM  -sum


Count    : 21
Average  :
Sum      : 1172385792
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : PM
```